# Webpack: Disable lazy loading

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, webpack

I am trying use Ionic without `ionic-app-scripts` and using a custom webpack configuration. I am seeing that webpack literally creates 100 bundles/chunks. I believe this is due to lazy loading/imports inside the Ionic library. Is there a way to make webpack disable lazy loading?

A part of what webpack outputs is:

```
[./node_modules/@ionic/core/dist/esm-es5 lazy recursive ^\.\/.*\.entry\.js$ include: \.entry\.js$exclude: \.system\.entry\.js$] ./node_modules/@ionic/core/dist/esm-es5 lazy ^\.\/.*\.entry\.js$ include: \.entry\.js$ exclude: \.system\.entry\.js$ namespace object 160 bytes {index} [built]
```

Comment: This is just annoying and without considering compatibility.

Comment: Hi, how were able to get rid of this ?